# Creating a style and adding to the resource of a FrameworkElement from code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Take the following example xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="DemoWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Name="GridMain">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <StackPanel>
            <Label>First Content</Label>
            <Label>Second Content</Label>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It obviously results in GridMain and all child elements taking on the styles declared within Grid.Resources. I am wanting to do achieve the same goal in code-behind, but am struggling. I have the following:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Style style = new Style();
    style.TargetType = typeof(Grid);
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Grid.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Black));
    GridMain.Resources.Add("A", style);

    style = new Style();
    style.TargetType = typeof(Label);
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Label.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.White));
    GridMain.Resources.Add("B", style);

    //This line while setting the exact style of GridMain does not allow the styles to propogate to child elements.
    //GridMain.Style = GridMain.Resources["A"] as Style;
}
```

However it isn't working - the debugger confirms that the styles have been added to the resource dictionary. I have the feeling that I am missing something to refresh GridMain as it were to cause the changes in the resources to show. I cannot find anything to what this is.

Comment: Seriously, consider NOT doing it the code way or at least use some `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you, and appreciate your concern. Although while I appreciate it may go against the spirit of xaml and WPF - codebehind is how I must do it. If you have any solution I'd be very grateful. :)

Comment: Check out my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This works but read on,

Since none of your controls map to a style it will only work if you comment out global styles applied using `x:Key` (like you did but using an alternate syntax).

Now you could delete the resources first so it won't raise an exception when you add these new styles but well, it isn't very practical.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Name="GridMain">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <!--<Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Black" />
            </Style>-->
            <!--<Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Style>-->
        </Grid.Resources>

        <StackPanel>
            <Label>First Content</Label>
            <Label>Second Content</Label>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var style1 = new Style
            {
                TargetType = typeof(Grid)
            };

            style1.Setters.Add(new Setter(Panel.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.DeepSkyBlue));

            GridMain.Resources.Add(typeof(Grid), style1);

            var style2 = new Style
            {
                TargetType = typeof(Label)
            };

            style2.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.White));

            GridMain.Resources.Add(typeof(Label), style2);
        }
    }
}
```

You should really do it [the WPF way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0) for maximum flexibility:

- define a base style
- decorate your controls with `DynamicResource`
- create themes
- etc

You will then be able to switch themes very easily.

Comment: Thank you so much. Hm, to be honest I've just got a hatred for xaml, I find it so cumbersome. Nevertheless I'll endeavour to look at that article from MS - maybe I just need to embrace it more before dismissing it. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Thanks you welcome, good luck for your project :)